# Insert & Retrieve Image in Postgresql database form VBNet

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I want to insert and retrieve image in Postgresql database from VB.net on button click event. My table has one column "image" with datatype `bytea`. I have written below code but not getting desired output:

```
'Insert 
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim image1 As Byte()
            Dim FS As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\0.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim BR As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(FS)
            Dim lg As Long = FS.Length
            Dim length As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(lg)
            image1 = BR.ReadBytes(length)
            conn.Open()
            Dim Command As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO table2 Values(@image1)", conn)
            'Dim Command As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 values('" & timestamp & "','" & serialno & "','" & modelname & "','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0')", conn)
            Command.Parameters.Add(New NpgsqlParameter("@image1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea))
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
'retrieve
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim com As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("select image from table2", conn)
            Dim reader As NpgsqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()

            Dim imageInBytes As Byte() = reader("image")
            Dim memoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = _
                New System.IO.MemoryStream(imageInBytes, False)
            Dim image As System.Drawing.Image = _
                System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream)
            image.Save("E:\image")
            PictureBox6.Image = image
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need values in parameters in 'Insert'...Change this...

```vb
   Dim Command As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO table2 Values(@image1)", conn)            
   Command.Parameters.Add(New NpgsqlParameter("image1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea))
```

For this...

```vb
   Dim Command As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO table2 Values(:image1)", conn)
   Dim param As NpgsqlParameter = New NpgsqlParameter("image1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea)
   param.Value = image1
   Command.Parameters.Add(param)
```

And in 'Retrieve' you need take length before... Change this...

```vb
   Dim imageInBytes As Byte() = reader("image")
  Dim memoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = _
      New System.IO.MemoryStream(imageInBytes, False)
  Dim image As System.Drawing.Image = _
      System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream)
  image.Save("E:\image")
  PictureBox6.Image = image
```

For something similar to this...

```vb
   Dim imageInBytes As Byte()
   reader.Read()

   ' Retrieve the length of the necessary byte array.
   Dim column as integer = reader.GetOrdinal("name_column")
   Dim len As Long = reader.GetBytes(column, 0, Nothing, 0, 0)

   ' Create a buffer to hold the bytes, and then 
   ' read the bytes from DataReader.
   ReDim imageInBytes(CInt(len))
   reader.GetBytes(column, 0, imageInBytes, 0, CInt(len))
   PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(New MemoryStream(imageInBytes))
```